# Rotating 3D object without Plane Tracker in Spark AR

Tags: 3d, spark-ar-studio

Is there any way of rotating a 3d object without plane tracker? We can rotate an object with the plane tracker, I'm seeking a way of rotating an object without that. 
Any one know about this?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Here is my answer[image]